# how I secure my source code over client domain network

Tags: java, php, spring, security, encryption

Ok so we are at sitting client location, our all system is running on domain,the network team provided by the client belonging to other organisation, network team monitor development department, they are able to read as well as write in our system by remotely logging into it.

They provide security but as an organisation its our responsibility to secure our source code so we need more security from our end, so we want to secure more our overall source code.

My organisation working on Java,Java FX,Spring MVC, Oracle DB,PHP,JDBC template, and we already delivered 10+ web applications and providing maintenance and support to client.

so guys what is the best suitable encryption technology we need to implement in our existing system so no one can able to access source code via remote too.

kindly provide your valuable suggestion, I welcoming to all of you

Comment: I'm not sure, if this question fits here

Comment: ok then suggest me the best place where i can get my answer, thank you

Comment: This should part of your research, you have Google with you.

Comment: Yes Ravi, I do have my research on it, the reason i put it here that i just wanna know  suggestion from you talented and experienced people. if you can help me so kindly provide your suggestion too. Thanks

Comment: Then, you should have summarized your research and should have asked very specific question. This is very broad and opinion based

Comment: ok Ravi thanks for your suggestion, I will soon share my research part with you people.

Comment: There is source code encryption software out there.  Like ionCube for PHP.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark how you correlate my problem statement with licensing? unnecessary comment. Kindly provide suggestion only if you are able to understand my problem statement thank you

Comment: If you're trying to defend source code from your client, then this 100% a legal issue...

Comment: agreed, but i am here to know about the technology or the suggestions from you people which can help me to achieve my goal, so it sounds technical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't trust someone who has root access on a system, don't store data on it. The only way to surely secure your data is by having a server with you as root/administrator. You still can give user permissions to your client's system administrators for networking etc, but key point is you being the owner of the server for your time there.

Encryption may not be helpful as the root can subvert the program that doing decryption.

Comment: That's exaclty we need to implement thanks chaitanya